# Angular Velocity around an ellipse

Tags: geometry, mathematical-physics, mathematical-astronomy

I'm investigating into the angular velocity of a planet in its elliptical orbit.

I have these variables defined:

- speed of planet.
- speed of planet at perigee and apogee.
- length of orbit.
- time of orbit.
- distance away from center at apogee and perigee.

Is there a way from this data that I can calculate the *angular velocity of the planet in this orbit* ?.

$\tt\mbox{I need the angular velocities of all the 8 planets.}$

I've already done this all for a circular orbit which is quite easy but I can't figure out how to do it for elliptical orbits. Any help will be appreciated !. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Kepler's laws of planetary motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion), "a line segment joining a planet and the Sun sweeps out equal areas during equal intervals of time". This gives you the angular velocity:

$$
{dA\over dt}=r^2{d\theta\over dt}=k
$$
You can work out the velocity vector from that and the direction of motion. Note this assumes the sun is at one focus of the ellipse.

Comment: Yes but how can that help obtain an orbital velocity function? Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you that helps! Another question. The angular velocity will vary around the orbit right? So say if I had to compare the angular velocity of one elliptical orbit with another to check for a time of overlap how would this be approached? Thanks